# leer excel correctamente en C#

Tags: c#

tengo un problema que no he podido solucionar, resulta que estoy cargando un excel desde un aplicativo mvc lo capturo lo leo y lo paso a un datatable hasta ahí todo perfecto pero resulta que el excel esta en formato Percentage (%) y las celdas estan en el mismo formato cuando lo capturo con el datatable me toma el valor en porcentaje y lo leo como string ejemplo en la celda del excel aparece 12%, el valor de la celda cuando uno lo ve es "12.46997%" y cuando lo capturo en c# me lee solo el 12% no el resto de los decimales que trae.

Unas fotos de ejemplo.

[image: Asi esta el excel]

El valor del excel tiene decimales.

acá como lo captura mi codigo c#

[image: codigo]

Nose como recibirlo, nose si hay alguna manera de cuando leo el excel desde el codigo convertir a formato numerico.

aca mi codigo:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProrrataRetiroCarga(HttpPostedFileBase fileProrrataRetiro)

    {
        string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(fileProrrataRetiro.FileName);
        string filepath = "/excelFolder/" + filename;
        fileProrrataRetiro.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/excelFolder/"), filename));
        InsertExceldata(filepath, filename);
        ViewData["Success"] = "Archivo Cargado Exitosamente.";
        return View("~/Views/ProrrataRetiro/ProrrataRetiro.aspx");
    }
    private void ExcelConn(string filepath)
    {
        string constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro; HDR=YES;""", filepath);
        Econ = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    }
    private void InsertExceldata(string fileepath, string filename)
    {
        string fullpath = Server.MapPath("/excelFolder/") + filename;
        ExcelConn(fullpath);
        string query = string.Format("Select * from[PRORRATA_RETIROS$]");

        OleDbCommand Ecom = new OleDbCommand(query, Econ);
        Econ.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, Econ);
        Econ.Close();
        oda.Fill(ds);
        ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dt.Rows[0].Delete();
        dt.Rows[1].Delete();
        dt.Rows[2].Delete();
        dt.Rows[3].Delete();
        dt.Rows[4].Delete();
        dt.Rows[5].Delete();
        dt.Rows[6].Delete();
        dt.AcceptChanges();

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataTable dtpaso = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dcCol = new DataColumn();
            dcCol.ColumnName = "nomEmpresa";
            dtpaso.Columns.Add(dcCol);
            dcCol = new DataColumn();
            dcCol.ColumnName = "Hora";
            dtpaso.Columns.Add(dcCol);
            dcCol = new DataColumn();
            dcCol.ColumnName = "Porc";
            dtpaso.Columns.Add(dcCol);



            for (int fila = 0; fila < dt.Rows.Count; fila++)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[fila][0].ToString() != "")
                {
                    for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
                    {
                        if (dt.Rows[fila][col].ToString().Trim() != "")
                        {
                            DataRow drPaso = dtpaso.NewRow();
                            drPaso["nomEmpresa"] = dt.Rows[0][col + 1].ToString();
                            drPaso["Hora"] = dt.Rows[fila + 1][0];
                            drPaso["Porc"] = (((dt.Rows[fila + 1][col + 1]).ToString()) != "#REF!") ? dt.Rows[fila + 1][col+1].ToString() : "0";
                         //   var numero = dt.Rows[fila + 1][col+1];                             
                            dtpaso.Rows.Add(drPaso);
                            dtpaso.AcceptChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            col = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Revisa este [enlace #1](http://codehill.com/2009/01/reading-excel-2003-and-2007-files-using-oledb/) o este [enlace #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12316998/4092887). Si entendí bien el enlace #1, parece que tiene que ver con los parámetros del connectionstring usado para leer el Excel. Si no lo has considerado aún, busca `Loosing precision while reading the values from Excel in C#`. Siento no poder ayudarte mas. Saludos.

Comment: Le coloqué IMEX=1; pensando que así me iba a capturar el valor completo y no hubo ninguna diferencia. :/

Comment: Joel, si no encuentra una solución, considere usar otra manera de acceder a los datos del archivo Excel *(ya sea usando Interop, EPPlus, o alguna otra alternativa)*.

Answer (score 1):

Joel, el problema es que estás tomando el dato como string, debes transformar a decimal. Cambia la línea:

```
drPaso["Porc"] = (((dt.Rows[fila + 1][col + 1]).ToString()) != "#REF!") ? 
dt.Rows[fila + 1][col+1].ToString() : "0";
```

Por esta:

```
If(dt.Rows[fila + 1][col + 1].ToString() != "#REF!")
{
  string dato = Rows[fila + 1][col + 1].ToString().Replace("%","");
  drPaso["Porc"] = decimal.Parse(dato).ToString();
}
Else
  drPaso["Porc"] = "0";
```

Comment: con esto soluciono el sacar el simbolo % pero no, el que cuando subo el excel me detecta solo 12 y no el resto del numero que en el caso por ejemplo no es 12% solamente. Es 12.45634% y el resto no lo toma.

Comment: Entonces debes cambiar el valor del tipo de dato en el regedit (TypeGuessRows) ejecuta regedit. Sigue estos pasos y me cuentas cómo te va http://support.sas.com/kb/35/563.html